# TimeOnly data type is not supported in Dapper in C# .NET6 API project

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-6.0, dapper

I am using Dapper in an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project with SQL Server 2016 database as backend. The `ExecuteScalar` method of Dapper is returning an error

> The member DepartureTime of type System.TimeOnly cannot be used as a parameter value

Is there any workaround?

```
public virtual int Create(TModel entity)
{
    int result = -1;
    var insertQuery = QueryGenerator.GenerateInsertQuery(typeof(TModel));
    var factory = new SqlServerDbConnectionFactory(connectionString);
    var profiler = CustomDbProfiler.Current;

    using (var connection = ProfiledDbConnectionFactory.New(factory, profiler))
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                connection.Open();
            }

            result =  connection.ExecuteScalar<int>(insertQuery, entity, transaction: null); // Throwing error
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var sql = profiler.GetCommands();
            throw;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

`insertQuery` contains the following query:

```
INSERT INTO [Flight] ([FlightNumber], [SourceCode], [DestinCode],[DepartureTime], [EffectDate], [Stops], [TravelMinutes]) 
VALUES (@FlightNumber, @SourceCode, @DestinCode, @DepartureTime, @EffectDate, @Stops, @TravelMinutes);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

`entity` is of type `FlightModel`:

```
public class FlightModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FlightNumber{ get; set; }
    public string SourceCode{ get; set; }
    public string DestinCode { get; set; }
    public TimeOnly DepartureTime{ get; set; }
    public DateOnly EffectDate { get; set; }
    public int Stops{ get; set; }
    public int TravelMinutes { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [here](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues/1715#issuecomment-1146141064), make your own type handler:

Add the following to your configuration:

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new SqlTimeOnlyTypeHandler());
```

- 

```
public class SqlTimeOnlyTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<TimeOnly>
{
    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, TimeOnly time)
    {
        parameter.Value = time.ToString();
    }

    public override TimeOnly Parse(object value)
    {
        return TimeOnly.FromTimeSpan((TimeSpan)value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `SetValue` use `time.ToTimeSpan()` instead of `time.ToString()`?

Comment: @DanGuzman: Why do you say that? Remember - This handler is only concerned with marshalling the `TimeOnly` value through the data access layer to the database.

Comment: Since the SQL Server time data type maps to .NET TimeSpan, I was under the impression the parameter value should be of type TimeSpan. But what I don't know about dapper type handlers is a lot so I'll defer to your expertise.

Comment: A similar approach can also be used for the `DateOnly` type.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `TimeSpan`:

```
public class FlightModel
{
    ...
    public TimeSpan DepartureTime{ get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectDate { get; set; }
}
```